# How can I change the activity that started with my android app?

Tags: android

Currently my ActivityMain.java is main in my app android. How can I change the activity that started with my android app ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: its confusing what you mean...as you use past tense(i have googled it to be 100% sure because english is not my motherlanguage) some might think that your app and therefore your activity has allready started and you want to change it now

Comment: @IljaKO There are people here from different parts of the world asking questions as good as they can. Its upon us to better understand the question. Or if you are not clear then comment the questioner and get clear IDEA first before answering the question

Comment: @Murtaza : the boardrules are clear, nevertheless he didn't change his question at all after my complain

Comment: You need to understand the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you manifest, put

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

between Activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name="com.some.activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```